# Where to put a counter variable?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm reading a file where each line gives some information for some certain instance in time. I want to assign each person an ID in the order in which they're read beginning at `0` and so on. Each person will be stored in a `person_info` object. The way I'm thinking of numbering the ids is to have a static global_id variable inside the `person_info` class that increments every time the constructor is called as shown below.

However, when I think about this, I feel this design is not very good because I could accidentally create a copy somewhere, and that would end up calling the constructor and subsequently increasing the `global_id` and then I would have a situation where the series of IDs are not contiguous (though that really doesn't break down any part of my code because it does not rely on contiguity). Aside from that are there other issues with this approach that you can think of?

The other idea is I'll just keep a `global_id` variable outside of the `person_info` class, and perhaps put it in my parsing function, and then when I construct the `person_info` object, I'll pass it into the constructor and then increment `global_id` before getting to the next person's information. That'll take care of the non-contiguity "issue," but I don't like the idea of having the `global_id` sitting outside of the only place it's going to be used in (i.e., the `person_info` struct). Ideally, I want to encapsulate it within where its actually used.

```
struct person_info
{
  person_info() : id{global_id} {++global_id;}
  inline static int global_id = 0;
  // there's a bunch more variables not shown here
};
```

Comment: The problem of constructing a `person_info` that does not correspond to a person in the data, thereby fouling the ID sequence, will still exist no matter where you store the counter.

Comment: You're facing a design issue that is partially personal opinion and partially perspective-based. If you were to think of this as an organization instead of a program, with one employee taking applications (reading from the file) and another filing away records (constructing `person_info`), to whom would you give the responsibility of assigning numbers? Who has the greater stake in ensuring the IDs are sequential and non-repetitive? (The issue with copying is easily overcome, but that's not what you asked about.) I'd kick this one back to the designer.

Answer (score 0):

> I could accidentally create a copy somewhere, and that would end up calling the constructor and subsequently increasing the global_id

You could create a copy constructor.

```
class person_info {
  person_info(const person_info& other)
    : id(other.id)
  {}
};
```

Or delete the copy constructor so you are not allowed to do so.

```
class person_info {
  person_info(const person_info&) = delete;
  person_info& operator=(const person_info&) = delete;
};
```